# How to Capture Gmail id used for Android market

Tags: android, email

I am using the following code to get android's primary email id.

```
       String possibleEmail = null;

    Pattern emailPattern = Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS; // API level 8+
    Account[] accounts = AccountManager.get(getBaseContext()).getAccounts(); {
    for (Account account : accounts) {
    if (emailPattern.matcher(account.name).matches()) {
    possibleEmail = account.name;
    }
    }

    final TextView user = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.username);
    user.setText(possibleEmail);}

}
```

Problem with this code is It returns different email ids when a user adds a new email account on their device. For ex. In my device at the time of installing the app. there was only one email account that is primary gmail account used for play store.But When i added an another active sync email id, This code returns the second id. I want to capture their android market id only. Why i am particular about that is Already i have those email ids registered in my mysql db. Only my company employees should use this app and no authentication required for them whey they access from the android device (registered gmail id)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That code you are using is looping through all the accounts with email addresses and setting `possibleEmail` to the last one found.

Maybe what you want is to find the accounts with `type="com.google"` and if there is more than one display the list to the user and allow them to select the google account they want to use for logging in.

this seems to work for me for finding the google accounts:

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
tv.setText("");

Pattern emailPattern = Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS;
Account[] accounts = AccountManager.get(getBaseContext()).getAccounts();
for (Account account : accounts)
{
    if (emailPattern.matcher(account.name).matches() && account.type.equals("com.google"))
    {
        tv.append(account.name + "\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks I will try and let you know